# mysql return results grouped by every 2 days

Tags: mysql

I have an activity feed and would like to query my tables to grab all feed items by a user while also grouping them into intervals of 2 days.

so one feed item might say "user did these things 2 days ago" and it would show the feed item id for those actions.

My issue is that i can't figure out how to place each feed item into a group that is associated with a 2 day interval.

right now i have 45 results, all ranging throughout the month. the best i could do is do a `group by` where i group them by an internal of 2 days. but i need the to get the feed id's in the results and not a count.

for example

```
dayGroup | feedId
-------------------
1     | 300
1     | 301
2     | 400
2     | 401
```

in pseudo sql

```
select feedId from feeds where userid = 1 and feedType = "action" group by every 2 days
```

Further explanation on the day grouping.

If a feed item was created on 08-07-15, then look backwards 2 days from latest feed activity to 08-05-15 as a dayGroup and so on until there is no more feed items. This would be dynamic based on the actual latest date from an activity feed.

My table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE `activity_feed` (
  `feed_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `text` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `date_created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL,
  `section` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_user_id1` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_user_id2` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `data_game_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `layout` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `first_feed_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`feed_id`),
  KEY `idx1` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `idx2` (`section`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `af_fk1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1838 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: table schema please. thx. so dayGroup ranges from 1 to 16 ?

Comment: Define day. I suspect that once you've done that you will have answered your own question

Comment: i edited with an explanation on what i mean by day

Comment: @drew yes, i suppose that would be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### schema:

```
create table dtGrpTwo
(   gno int not null,   -- group number
    dom int not null    -- day of month
);
insert dtGrpTwo (gno,dom) values (1,1),(1,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,5),(3,6),(4,7),(4,8);   -- etc up to group 16

create table evts
(
    feed_id int auto_increment primary key,
    user_id int not null,
    feedType varchar(55) not null,
    date_created datetime not null
);
-- truncate table evts;
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-11-01');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-11-02');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'PULSE','2014-11-02');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-11-02');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-11-02');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-11-05');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'PULSE','2014-11-05');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-11-08');

insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-12-08');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-12-08');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (1001,'ACTION','2014-12-08');

insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (666,'ACTION','2014-11-01');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (666,'ACTION','2014-11-02');
insert evts (user_id,feedType,date_created) values (666,'ACTION','2014-11-02');
```

### query:

```
select g.gno as dayGroup,e.feed_id
from dtGrpTwo g
join evts e
on dayofmonth(e.date_created)=g.dom
and e.user_id=1001
and feedType='ACTION'
and e.date_created between '2014-11-01' and '2014-11-30'
order by g.gno,e.feed_id
```

### results:

```
+----------+---------+
| dayGroup | feed_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       1 |
|        1 |       2 |
|        1 |       4 |
|        1 |       5 |
|        3 |       6 |
|        4 |       8 |
+----------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: ah, i see! i didn't think about using the between clause in conjunction with the rest of the query.

Comment: also check out the last_day() function [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) in mysql. good luck.